# Add table in a different excel application

Tags: excel, vba

I create each day a file gathering data from different excel sheets and doing calculations only once a day. When this file is created, this file is used different times a day. This file is created by a macro if it is not present yet. When I open a file, this is displayed on the screen. To hide opening all those file, I created a second excel instance that stays hidden. The problem is that I cannot create a table in a sheet in the second instance.

This is the code:

```
Dim app As New Excel.Application
app.Visible = False

Set newWB = app.Workbooks.Add
With newWB
    .Title = "Summarizing of systemparts information"
    .Subject = "Systemparts"
    .SaveAs assembledSheet
End With

app.newWB.Sheets("SystemParts").ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range("$A$1:$CN$55"), , xlYes).Name = "SystemP"
app.ActiveSheet.ListObjects("SystemP").TableStyle = "TableStyleLight8"
```

Is there an option to solve this problem?

Comment: You could just use `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` at the start instead of opening a new Excel instance...and then turn it back on at the end of your code.

Comment: That does not cover for opening other files. I would like to hide to the user that in the background, other excel files are opened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to add a table to a sheet that you haven't created yet.
You create the new workbook, but fail to specify which sheet is 'SystemParts'.

```
Sub Test()

    Dim app As Excel.Application
    Dim newWB As Workbook
    Dim newWS As Worksheet
    Dim x As Long

    'Create new Excel instance and add a new workbook.
    Set app = New Excel.Application
    Set newWB = app.Workbooks.Add

    With newWB
        'Add a sheet to the end of the workbook.
        Set newWS = .Worksheets.Add(, .Worksheets(.Worksheets.Count))

        'Remove all other sheets.
        'As you delete sheet Index 1 - the next sheet replaces it,
        'so just remove the first index each time.
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        For x = 1 To .Worksheets.Count - 1
            .Worksheets(1).Delete
        Next x
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True

        'Name the new sheet and add a table.
        With newWS
            .Name = "SystemParts"
            .ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, .Range("$A$1:$CN$55"), , xlYes).Name = "SystemP"
            .ListObjects("SystemP").TableStyle = "TableStyleLight8"
        End With

        .SaveAs ThisWorkbook.Path & "\NewWB.xlsx"


    End With

End Sub
```